# The best database design for multistage forms?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have multiple forms (actually one single form which has some sections) with a progress bar like:

```
// ----- Request Being Agent Form -----

CEO-Basics: f-name, l-name, age, mobile, email, address, fax, education
Staff-basics: f-name, l-name, email
Company: name, staff-num, permissions, documents, business-scope, target-segment
```

As you can see, both `CEO` and `Staff`s are human. But we need more details for `CEO`. Should I keep them in the same table (in the database) and set details `null` for `Staff`s ?

Or do I need to make one table which has lots of columns for all form's files? *(however it doesn't make sense, because an agent can has multiple staff)*

Noted that currently I have a table named `users` which keeps all my users's data. Should I expand it and use it for storing both `CEO` and `Staff` data? Or any better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would do something like the following:

I created 3 tables (personnel, sup_detail, company) as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS personnel;
CREATE TABLE personnel 
(
  personnel_id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  f_name VARCHAR(30), 
  l_name VARCHAR(50), 
  email VARCHAR(255)
);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sup_detail;
CREATE TABLE sup_detail
(
  p_id INTEGER, 
  age INTEGER, 
  mobile VARCHAR(50), 
  address VARCHAR(100), 
  fax VARCHAR(50), 
  education VARCHAR(500)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company;
CREATE TABLE company 
(
  company_id INTEGER,
  company_name VARCHAR(50), 
  staff_num INTEGER -- left out other fields - no data type, not relevant to the point at hand anyway
);
```

Now, the data:

For CEO's:

```
INSERT INTO personnel (f_name, l_name, email) 
VALUES ('Bill', 'Gates', 'bgates@msoft.com');
```

Now, we get the id from the last insert. This is a very useful MySQL construct - other systems use the `RETURNING` clause.

```
SET @id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Now, we put that id into the extra sup_detail table.

```
INSERT INTO sup_detail 
VALUES (@id, 70, '111-222-333', 'Big  House, Seattle', '333-222-111', 'College dropout');
```

Ordinary workers:

```
INSERT INTO personnel (f_name, l_name, email) VALUES ('Joe', 'Bloggs', 'jbloggs@blah.com');
INSERT INTO personnel (f_name, l_name, email) VALUES ('Sean', 'Sixpack', 'ssixpack@xyz.com');
INSERT INTO personnel (f_name, l_name, email) VALUES ('Homer', 'Simpson', 'hsimpson@springfield.com');
```

Company data:

```
INSERT INTO company VALUES (56, 'Oracle', '100000');
```

Now, most of the time, you'll only be querying the personnel table for f_name, l_name and email, but, if you do require full details, you can run a query like this:

```
SELECT p.f_name, p.l_name, p.email, sd.age, COALESCE(sd.mobile, 'N/A')
FROM personnel p
LEFT OUTER JOIN sup_detail sd
ON p.personnel_id = sd.p_id;
```

Result:

```
f_name  l_name      email                      age  mobile
Bill    Gates       bgates@msoft.com            70  111-222-333
Joe     Bloggs      jbloggs@blah.com          null  N/A
Sean    Sixpack      ssixpack@xyz.com         null  N/A
Homer   Simpson      hsimpson@springfield.com null  N/A
```

You could have `COALESCE(sd.age, 0)`- but an age of 0 doesn't really make much sense.

Now, in order to have a list of what are sometimes called  `legal persons` (both can own shares for example), we do the following:

```
SELECT p.personnel_id, CONCAT(p.f_name, ' ', p.l_name) AS the_name
FROM personnel p
UNION
SELECT c.company_id, c.company_name
FROM company c
```

Result:

```
the_id  the_name
     1  Bill Gates
     2  Joe Bloggs
     3  Sean Sixpack
     4  Homer Simpson. 
    56  Oracle
```

The only tricky bit is to ensure that the personnel_id and company_id don't clash - my advice here is to have some sort of multiplier and add that to a generated id using, say, a BIGINT + id. The SQL &c. from above are available on a fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3abnDAkFVZe8mmP1PWXxbK/0).